# Are any Service Canada offices in Vancouver open during the weekend/evenings?

Tags: canada, taxes

I need to apply for a Canadian [Social Security Number](https://www.canada.ca/en/employment-social-development/services/sin/apply.html), for which I need to visit a Service Canada office in person. Unfortunately from what I can find on their website all of their offices are open 8:30AM-4:00PM, which is quite inconvenient for a working person.

Is it possible to get a Social Security Number outside the working hours? It might sound like a naive question, but I've already found out that some banks are open on Saturday and likewise the ICBC has some offices open during the weekend, so perhaps there's a trick to Social Security Numbers as well.

Comment: Most employers hiring a foreign immigrant should understand and accommodate that the new employee will need to do some bureaucratic errands during working hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope. All Service Canada offices operate on hours similar to what you mentioned (with some exceptions maybe). Had the same problem but no luck.

Remember that you wouldn't even be hired in most professions without a valid SIN number. So that's the first thing you want to do (before even joining work). Just take some time off after arriving to Canada and before joining work and apply for a SIN number. The employer should understand your reason. It takes an hour max to apply for and get the SIN number.

Also make sure that its been atleast 24 hours since you landed at the border when you apply for it since Service Canada once told me that their information is not updated until 24 hours.

Comment: I'm starting work already, so I guess I just have to apply for it by taking time off :)